# How to keep session variables between pages with forms?

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, session

I'm writing a program that has 3 pages.

On page 1 there is an option for the user to select a quantity of a breakfast product he wants to purchase. After selecting a quantity the user hits the submit button, if the user is not registered, it will take him to Page 2 for him to register. If the user is registered, it will direct them to Page 3.

However, if the user goes to Page 2 first and does not have a quantity selected from Page 1 it will redirect him to Page 1 after he registers and press submit, and then once they select a quantity and hit submit on Page 1 it will go to Page 3.

I'm struggling to maintain my session variables between the pages because two of them have forms that get overwritten if the user ever goes back to that page.

Page 1:

```
<?php 
session_start();
    $_SESSION['name']= $_POST['name'];
    $_SESSION['email']= $_POST['email'];
    $platter_quantity = $_SESSION['platter_quantity'];
    $yogurt_quantity = $_SESSION['yogurt_quantity'];
    $waffles_quantity = $_SESSION['waffles_quantity'];
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Product Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type"text/css" href="settings.css">
</head>
<html>
<body>

<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="product.php">Product</a></li>
  <li><a href="registration.php">Registration</a></li>
  <li><a href="invoice.php">Invoice</a></li>
  <li style="float:right"><a href="registration.php">Login</a></li>
</ul>

<?php
$action = '';
if (!empty($_SESSION['name']) or !empty($_SESSION['email'])) {
    $action = "invoice.php";
    }
else {
    $action = "registration.php";
    }
?>

<form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post">
<div class="container">
    <img src="images/platter.jpg" alt="Breakfast Platter" style="float: left; width: 400px; height: 300px;";>
    <h1>Breakfast Platter</p>
    <p>The breakfast platter option comes with two fried eggs, four pancakes, and a bunch of bacon.</p>
    Quantity: <input type="number" name="platter_quantity" min="0">
    <p value="10.99" name="platter_price">Price: $10.99</p>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <img src="images/yogurt.jpg" alt="Yogurt Parfait" style="float: left; width: 400px; height: 300px;">
    <h1>Yogurt Parfait</p>
    <p>The yogurt parfait option comes with two cups of yogurt, oats, and a mixture of berries.</p>
    Quantity: <input type="number" name="yogurt_quantity" min="0">
    <p value="6.99" name="yogurt_price">Price: $6.99</p>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <img src="images/waffles.jpg" alt="Waffles" style="float: left; width: 400px; height: 300px;";>
    <h1>Waffles</p>
    <p>The waffles option comes with two buttermilk waffles with butter and syrup.</p>
    Quantity: <input type="number" name="waffles_quantity" min="0">
    <p value="$4.99" name="waffles_price">Price: $4.99</p>
</div>

<br>
    <button class="button" type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Page 2:

```
<?php
session_start();
    $name = $_SESSION['name'];
    $email = $_SESSION['email'];
    $_SESSION['platter_quantity'] = $_POST['platter_quantity'];
    $_SESSION['yogurt_quantity'] = $_POST['yogurt_quantity'];
    $_SESSION['waffles_quantity'] = $_POST['waffles_quantity'];
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Registration Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type"text/css" href="settings.css">
</head>
<html>
<body>

<ul>
  <li><a href="product.php">Product</a></li>
  <li><a class="active" href="registration.php">Registration</a></li>
  <li><a href="invoice.php">Invoice</a></li>
  <li style="float:right"><a href="registration.php">Login</a></li>
</ul>
<br>

<?php
$action = '';
if (!empty($_SESSION['platter_quantity']) or !empty($_SESSION['yogurt_quantity']) or !empty($_SESSION['waffles_quantity'])) {
    $action = "invoice.php";
    }
else {
    $action = "product.php";
    }
?>

<form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name" pattern="[A-Za-z]" required><br><br>
    E-mail: <input type="text" name="email" pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/" required><br><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<br>
<?php
print_r($_SESSION);
echo "<br>Platter: " . $_SESSION["platter_quantity"] . "<br>";
echo "Yogurt: " . $_SESSION["yogurt_quantity"] . "<br>";
echo "Waffles: " . $_SESSION["waffles_quantity"];
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Page 3:

```
<?php 
session_start();
    $name = $_SESSION['name'];
    $email = $_SESSION['email'];
    $platter_quantity = $_SESSION['platter_quantity'];
    $yogurt_quantity = $_SESSION['yogurt_quantity'];
    $waffles_quantity = $_SESSION['waffles_quantity'];
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Invoice Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type"text/css" href="settings.css">
</head>
<html>
<body>

<ul>
  <li><a href="product.php">Product</a></li>
  <li><a href="registration.php">Registration</a></li>
  <li><a class="active" href="invoice.php">Invoice</a></li>
  <li style="float:right"><a href="registration.php">Login</a></li>
</ul>

<h1>Hi! Welcome <?php  echo $_SESSION['name']; ?>! </h1>
<?php
print_r($_SESSION);
echo "<br>Platter: " . $platter_quantity . "<br>";
echo "Yogurt: " . $yogurt_quantity . "<br>";
echo "Waffles: " . $waffles_quantity;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

What's the best way for me to implement this using session variables without using a database?

I tried doing this as well, but it did not seem to work:

```
<?php 
session_start();
    if (empty($_SESSION['name']) or empty($_SESSION['email'])) {
        $_SESSION['name'] = $POST_['name'];
        $_SESSION['email'] = $POST_['email'];
    }
    else {
        $name = $_SESSION['name'];
        $name = $_SESSION['email'];
    }

    if (empty($_SESSION['platter_quantity']) or empty($_SESSION['yogurt_quantity']) or ($_SESSION['waffles_quantity'])) {
        $_SESSION['platter_quantity'] = $POST_['platter_quantity'];
        $_SESSION['yogurt_quantity'] = $POST_['yogurt_quantity'];
        $_SESSION['waffles_quantity'] = $POST_['waffles_quantity'];
    }
    else {
        $platter_quantity = $_SESSION['platter_quantity'];
        $yogurt_quantity = $_SESSION['yogurt_quantity'];
        $waffles_quantity = $_SESSION['waffles_quantity'];
    }
?>
```

Comment: maybe check if it's empty before overwriting? `if(empty($_SESSION['name'])) $_SESSION['name']= $_POST['name'];`

Comment: I tried doing this and it doesn't seem to be saving the session variables at all now.

Comment: Would I be able to create a blank page that would save the form session variables and then redirect them to the appropriate page? I think this would allow me to assign the session variables without them ever getting overwritten.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never insert $_POST or $_GET without first checking if they're set `isset($_POST['variable'])`, and you can use checks here as well - do a check for the existence of $_POST-variables, and if they exist, use them, and if not, assign the $_SESSION-variables. So on page 3, you will have something like:

```
$name = $_SESSION['name'] = (isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : ((isset($_SESSION['name']) ? $_SESSION['name'] : '')));
```

And so on for the other variables. What this does is checks for $_POST, and if it's set, it updates the $_SESSION-variable, and if it's not set, it just updates the $_SESSION-variable with the already existing $_SESSION-variable, and if that doesn't exist either, it sets both variables `$name` and `$_SESSION['name']` to empty, which you then can check for later in the script (and redirect etc.)

Comment: Would I implement this on every single page?

Comment: This is also missing a parenthesis and I'm not entirely sure where the first statement is suppose to end or if it's just one big statement.

Comment: Sorry, I updated the code, it should be correct now. It's one big statement, just for the `$name`- it's called a ternary operator. And yes, you would implement this on every page where you COULD arrive from the forms. On any other page I would assume that the `$_SESSION` would already be set, and there is no need to check.

Comment: However, I did notice one thing. If the customer ever wants to change the quantity from the first page back to 0, this code doesn't allow it and just keeps the session variable they had before.

Comment: I didn't think about that - removed the check for `empty` - you should perhaps have some more checks, to see if the quantity is set as a number, but that might not be that important.

Comment: The number check isn't important because it only allows them to select positive numbers starting from 0, they don't actually type anything in.

Comment: Well... that's what you have set in the HTML-code. That is removed in about 5 seconds, if I want to. Not that your users are probably gonna be that well-versed in coding, but that isn't really a check, or deterrent, it's just aiding users a bit. You should still check for the content on the server-side, especially if this is gonna be public / on the web.